# How can I replace a matrix element using logical indexing?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

The following is my matrix,

```
coords = [
     1    -1;
     1     0;
   219     1;
   219     2;
   219     3;];
```

.

Suppose, I want to replace elements of the **2nd column**, which are less than 1, with 1.

I.e., my expected matrix would be,

```
coords = [
     1     1;
     1     1;
   219     1;
   219     2;
   219     3;];
```

So, I tried to do the following,

```
coords(:,coords(:, 2)<1) = 1;
```

It is not working.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you almost got it:

```
 coords(coords(:,2)<1,2)=1;
```

it is the first entry you want to edit at the 2nd col...